# Count most frequent element in a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following question.

I have to columns and I want for each unique entry the first column the most frequent element of the second column. An Example would be:

```
COL A    COL B
1        a
2        c
2        c
1        a
1        b
2        d
```

The query should  output:

```
Col A    COL B
1        a
2        c
```

Comment: Count(id) as total, order by ascending group by id and limit2

Comment: You have to use `Window` functions for this. Sadly MySQL doesn't support these. Another way would be to use a subquery as a column.

Answer (score 1):

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`a` int, `b` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`a`, `b`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'c'),
    (2, 'c'),
    (1, 'a'),
    (1, 'b'),
    (2, 'd')
;
```

you first have to get the count for each with a query like this:

```
SELECT
a, b,
COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM
t
GROUP BY 
a, b
```

Then you can use this query as a subquery to get the rows where a certain column holds the maximum. There's a nice article about this in the manual: [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Choosing for example the last method described in said article, your final query would be this:

```
SELECT sq1.a, sq1.b FROM
(
    SELECT
    a, b,
    COUNT(*) AS amount
    FROM
    t
    GROUP BY 
    a, b
) sq1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
    a, b,
    COUNT(*) AS amount
    FROM
    t
    GROUP BY 
    a, b
) sq2 ON sq1.a = sq2.a AND sq1.amount < sq2.amount
WHERE sq2.amount IS NULL;
```

With this result:

```
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    2 | c    |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a subselect in the `SELECT` clause is a simple way to solve your problem:

```
SELECT ColA, (SELECT ColB
    FROM yourtable i
    WHERE i.ColA = o.ColA
    GROUP BY ColB
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1) AS ColB
FROM yourtable o
GROUP BY ColA;
```

`o` is just an alias for the outer query, `i` for the inner query. They're needed for the `WHERE` clause to work.

The above query is a result of the following query to find the most common occurence of `ColB` with a given `ColA`:

```
SELECT ColB
FROM yourtable
WHERE ColA = 1 -- Replace 1; this is where the magic happens in the above query
GROUP BY ColB
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to create My Sql function for this let say you function name is getMaxOccr so it will look like

```
CREATE FUNCTION `getMaxOccr`(val INT) 
RETURNS varchar(25) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN

DECLARE answer VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT '';

SELECT colb FROM `tablename` 
WHERE cola = val 
ORDER BY COUNT(colb) 
DESC    INTO answer;
RETURN answer;

END
```

Once this function is created than you simply have to call

```
SELECT cola,getMaxOccr(cola) from tablename GROUP BY cola
```

this will give you the list with what you are looking for hope this helps

Comment: Functions are often a bad idea if you can avoid them with standard SQL.